# KeyboardAvoidingView with ScrollView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am sort of new to react native and have one question that I did not find in react native documentation.

I am looking into this component `KeyboardAvoidingView`:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html

Question is simple - has anyone to get `KeyboardAvoidingView` to work nicely with `ScrollView`? I have many `TextInputs` in one component (sum of TextInputs height is bigger then device height), and once the keyboard appears, I have various issues..
If I use `View` instead of `ScrollView` then everything is fine, but I can't use it, since I need more space than the device height.. 
I Couldn't find anything about Scroll in the `KeyboardAvoidingView` documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 126):

This is what my solution would be, it works and scrolls automatically on focus input. I tried this on Expo.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column',justifyContent: 'center',}} behavior="padding" enabled   keyboardVerticalOffset={100}>
    <ScrollView>
        <View style={Styles.row}>
            //your view
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: worked for me in apk build, but not in expo build, no worries ha ha :D

Comment: worked amazing, thanks. Don't know why this one isn't the correct answer... he didn't even choose one.

Comment: I only needed `behavior="padding"`

Comment: Not the perfect behavior, but for me worked better than just using behavior="padding". Thank you.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.  It really makes sense to wrap the ```ScrollView``` in the ```KeyboardAvoidingView```

Comment: Is the `keyboardVerticalOffset={100}` just a wild guess or based on some actual keyboard height? AFAIK keyboards on Android have varying heights and as such this seems problematic to me. It does work nicely though with the default google keyboard, so thank you for that :)

Comment: It could work on multiple keyboard but haven't tested out on other except default keyboards

Comment: Thanks. The <KeyboardAvoidingView> creates a <View> component, so it needs to fit in parent/child like the <ScrollView>, so `{ flex:1 }` resolves this

Comment: It worked with behaviour='height' instead of padding and ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{height: deviceHeight+100}} for me

Comment: Where does Styles.row come from?

Comment: Styles is imported on top which contains React Styling

Comment: So is it pseudo code or is an actual import from a library? I can't find it under react-native.

Comment: It is custom code and not from any library. I just had a separate file for styling to maintain code cleanliness

Answer (score 53):

I also tried to find the solution on the internet, but I figured it out myself. I was able to make `keyboardAvoidingView` to work with `ScrollView` on the iPhone SE simulator.

I used padding type `position`, with `keyboardVerticalOffset` set to some higher value.  I hope this helps everybody who is trapped in this situation.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={...}>
      <ScrollView>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          keyboardVerticalOffset={100}
          behavior={"position"}
        >
          <TextInput style={styles.editInput} ... />
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: not perfect but work fine, I guess the offset is caused by some Header component (like the one created by react navigation)

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: In my situation, my buttons at the end of the form were stucked under the android's navigation bar (back, home, recent). Apparently, **KeyboardAvoidingView** was wrapping **ScrollView**. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

It looks like facebook has not yet implemented a solution for scrollViews. But I have found solution made by Wix, [react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview](https://github.com/wix/react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview) that works like it should :)

`npm i react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview --save`

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview';

<KeyboardAwareScrollView style={styles.container}>
  <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder={'My Input'} />
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Comment: Please be aware that there is a difference between `react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview` by Wix and `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` by APSL. Notice that extra dash in there? Got to love npm...

Comment: I can also add that both those different libraries broke my scroll view and added more and more padding at the bottom every time I entered the text field. Likely the way it combines with my flex code

Comment: Nevermind, that was being caused by a second nested KeyboardAvoidingView. There's not a huge amount of difference between the two modules but I have found that APSL's "with dash" is more responsive than Wix's

Comment: Is there a way to get the wix scrollview to scroll to the bottom when the keyboard is opened?

Comment: i.e. how can I add functionality s.t. when the input textbox is opened (which is not in the wix scrollview) it will scroll the scroll view all the way to the bottom?

Answer (score 20):

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
   <KeyboardAvoidingView
     style={{flex:1}}
     behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'position' : null}
     keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 50 : 70}
   >
    <ScrollView> // no need to put here style={{flex:1}}
      <TextInput />
      <TextInput />
      <TextInput />
      <TextInput />
    </ScrollView>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</View>
```

Comment: This should be marked as right answer. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Yes, this worked for me too, on iOS behavior = 'position'

Answer (score 9):

In my case I used:
 https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view.

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  ....
  <MyContainerComponent>
    ....
    <MyFormComponentWithInputs />
  </MyContainerComponent>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

It supports older RN versions too.

My text input was somewhere hidden deep is some custom child component of the ScrollView but the package worked great for both Android and iOS

Comment: Better than the keyboardVerticalOffset in my case. Really simple to use. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

The below code solved my issue

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView 
  style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column',justifyContent: 'center'}}
  behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"} 
  keyboardVerticalOffset={150}
  enabled>
     {renderForm()}  // renderForm render the long form with ScrollView
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: Hallelujah it works, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing this issue ,spent more than 4 hours to figure out this issue and lastly
find this solution.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column',justifyContent: 'center'}} behavior="position" enabled   keyboardVerticalOffset={200}>
<ScrollView>
  <Text style={{padding:10,fontSize:42}}>Text 1</Text>
  <Text style={{padding:10,fontSize:42}}>Text 2</Text>
  <Text style={{padding:10,fontSize:42}}>Text 3</Text>
  <Text style={{padding:10,fontSize:42}}>Text 4</Text>
  <Text style={{padding:10,fontSize:42}}>Text 5</Text>
  <Text style={{padding:10,fontSize:42}}>Text 6</Text>
  <Text style={{padding:10,fontSize:42}}>Text 7</Text>
  <Text style={{padding:10,fontSize:42}}>Text 8</Text>
  <Text style={{padding:10,fontSize:42}}>Text 9</Text>
  <Text style={{padding:10,fontSize:42}}>Text 10</Text>
  <Text style={{padding:10,fontSize:42}}>Text 11</Text>
  <Text style={{padding:10,fontSize:42}}>Text 12</Text>
  <TextInput style={styles.input}
    placeholder="Type some text...">
  </TextInput>
  </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, though I had a different approach that basically will calculate and positioning (using translateY) the view when the keyboard appears.

I have published the solution on github and NPM [react-native-spacer](https://github.com/hieunc229/react-native-spacer).

Comment: Thank you very much i was stuck in very bad code and tried so many things nothing worked but you saved my day

Answer (score 2):

After so many attempts, this is the one that works fine both for iOS & Android:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
    style={styles.keyboard}
    behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
    enabled
    keyboardVerticalOffset={10}
>
   <ScrollView>
   ...
   </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

As for the style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   keyboard: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'center',
   }
});
```

Comment: The default `flexDirection` for RN flex element is `column` so that style shouldn't be needed

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps:

- **Avoid using "flex"** on any parents of KeyboardAvoidingView
- Consider to no use **position:'absolute'** on childs
- **Do not animate the translationY** of any child component
- Set KeyboardAvoidingView's **behavior to 'padding'**
- Be sure the TextInput has a **fixed height** (multiline,minHeight,flex)

I think that KeyboardAvoidingView will consider the height of the input from top to bottom, so if you are using way too much flex props or animating the textInput's 'Y' position, it might not calculate correctly the distance between top and the input to avoid the keyboard on show.

***Also, position absolute on a child seems to make the parent (KeyboardAvoidingView) to move but the child not move***

Comment: Thanks this works fine (at least on Android).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried 2days to find proper solution and finally I found that.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
     style={{flex:1 }}
     keyboardVerticalOffset={40 }
     behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null}
   >
   <ScrollView >
  ….. .. . .
   …
   </ScrollView>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

You just have to give special attention for TextInput because it does not work on multiline TextInput,
For that the solution is

```
<TextInput  
   multiline={true}
   scrollEnabled={false}
  />
```

Hope this will work for you and save your time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Abhi Burk is correct but under one condition
You need to modify the `windowSoftInputMode` property to the `adjustPan` value.
This modification should be done in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Answer (score 0):

I spent couple of hours with iPhone 13 simulator, android pixel 2, and iPhone 8 device. This is the solution:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <Button />
 <Text />

  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null}  keyboardVerticalOffset={50} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Button />
        </View>
        <Text> </Text>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <TextInput />
          <TextInput />
          <TextInput />
          <TextInput />
        </View>

        <TextInput />

        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <TextInput />
          <TextInput />
          <TextInput />
        </View>
        <TextInput />
      </ScrollView>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  <Button />
</SafeAreaView>
```

Also

> keyboardVerticalOffset={100}

would not work with iOS device, leaving a blank view at the bottom of the scroll view above the button. moving the button inside the ScrollView would not help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for all of the devices since all devices have a different top inset if you are using SafeAreaView

```
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
...

const insets = useSafeAreaInsets()
return (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <KeyboardAvoidingView 
      behavior="padding" 
      style={{ flex: 1 }} 
      keyboardVerticalOffset={insets.top}
    >
      <ScrollView>{children}</ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  </SafeAreaView>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2024 Solution

One no longer needs external packages to accomplish this task. In my experiments, I found that it's best not to use `KeyboardAvoidingView` at all on Android devices.

Reusable component, tested on different Android & iOS devices

```js
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements'
import React, { MutableRefObject, ReactNode } from 'react'
import { Keyboard, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, ScrollView, TouchableWithoutFeedback, ViewStyle } from 'react-native'

type Props = {
  children: ReactNode
  scrollContentContainerStyle?: ViewStyle
  scrollViewRef?: MutableRefObject<ScrollView | null>
}

const KeyboardAvoidingScrollView: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, scrollContentContainerStyle = {}, scrollViewRef }) => {
  const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight()

  const renderScrollView = (
    <ScrollView
      contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, ...scrollContentContainerStyle }}
      contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="never"
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
      ref={scrollViewRef}
    >
      {children}
    </ScrollView>
  )

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') return renderScrollView

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }} behavior="padding" keyboardVerticalOffset={headerHeight}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>{renderScrollView}</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
}

export default KeyboardAvoidingScrollView
```

Usage example:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingScrollView>
  Your content goes inside here
</KeyboardAvoidingScrollView>
```

### Is softwareKeyboardLayoutMode: pan required?

I do **not** use `softwareKeyboardLayoutMode` inside `app.config.ts` (I am using expo)

### Limitations

Unfortunately, I have to report that with ALL current solutions, it does not work when using a screen as the presentation style 'modal' on iOS. In this case, the text input is unfortunately not properly aligned. Please inform me if someone has found a solution for this. Additionally, in this scenario, the height of the header is lower, and the entire page has less height.

### Multiline inputs

When working with multiline inputs, it is important to ensure the use of `scrollEnabled={false}` otherwise, the alignment does not work perfectly.

Answer (score -3):

Not the perfect behavior in ios platform , use KeyboardAwareScrollView instead of KeyboardAvoidingView.

Comment: Not a valid  candidate. Please provide more info on your answer.