# React Native KeyboardAvoidingView covers last text input

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using React Native's [Keyboard Avoiding View](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html) with the behavior set to padding (testing on Android).

I have multiple TextInputs on my screen. When I click the final TextInput, the keyboard covers it. I am now able to scroll down due to padding added from KeyboardAvoidingView, but it would be ideal to have it auto scroll on focus.

```
<Content>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding'>
    <TextInput placeholder='Example 1' />
    <TextInput placeholder='Example 2' />
    <TextInput placeholder='Example 3' />
    <TextInput placeholder='Example 4' />
    <TextInput placeholder='Example 5' />
    <TextInput placeholder='Example 6' />
    <TextInput placeholder='Example 7' />
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</Content>
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

there is prop called keyboardVerticalOffset that you can pass to the KeyboardAvoidingView that will change how much the keyboard moves past the textInput.
Sample of my code:

```
const keyboardVerticalOffset = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : 0

    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position' keyboardVerticalOffset={keyboardVerticalOffset}>
        <ListView .../>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView/>
    )
```

Comment: I found using 100 is more pleasing (personal opinion)

Comment: This helped my issue, i had to use a height of 140 though. This is likely due to the size of the text input itself, just so people are aware.

Answer (score 39):

Depending on platform, Android or IOS, implementation can be vary a little. This is how I did.

Add  **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"** at AndroidManifest.xml,

```
 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

 </activity>
```

In your container

```
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null}
      keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 64 : 0}>
      <ScrollView>
        {...}
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

**keyboardVerticalOffset** tells how much the keyboard moves past the textInput.

Comment: Thanks! Setting keyboardVerticalOffset as 64 is working perfectly to me. But not sure what this offset means, can you tell me some more details?

Comment: "This is the distance between the top of the user screen and the react native view, may be non-zero in some use cases." - https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview#keyboardverticaloffset

Answer (score 15):

[react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)

It's super simple to use and it worked great in both Android and iOS.

It supports older versions of RN too.

Initially I tried the `KeyboardAvoidingView` but on IOS not even

`behavior='position'` with `keyboardVerticalOffset` worked properly.

That used to overlap some content in a strange way.

I have:

```
RN 0.53.3
react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view 0.6.0
```

I added a few more details about my use case here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151496/1979861

Answer (score 7):

To add to @Maxwell's answer, sometimes you may need to scroll further than the end of the scroll view to get a component into view, since the added padding is not the full height of the keyboard. Full example below using scrollTo() with y offset as the height of the text input.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    ScrollView,
    View,
    TextInput
} from 'react-native'


export default class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style = {{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'white'}} ref = 'scroll'>
              <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position' style = {{backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1}}>
                    <View style = {{height: 400}}/>
                    <TextInput style = {{height: 60}} placeholder='Example 1' />
                    <TextInput style = {{height: 60}} placeholder='Example 2' />
                    <TextInput style = {{height: 60}} placeholder='Example 3' />
                    <TextInput style = {{height: 60}} placeholder='Example 4' onFocus = {() => this.refs['scroll'].scrollTo({y: 60})}/>
              </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Richard Millen. I tried this, but it seems to function differently depending on where I am on the screen.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using **react-navigation v6** you might need

```
import { useHeaderHeight } from "@react-navigation/elements";

 const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();

   <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : undefined}
        style={flexGrow}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? headerHeight + Constants.statusBarHeight : 0}
      >
   </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: This almost works but it is about 20 pixels off, which makes me suspect the status bar height is not being accounted for. I edited code appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

based on @Richard Millen something change in this styles

```
<ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={{
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: 20
  }}
>
  <TextInput
    style = {{ minHeight: 100 }}
  />
  <TextInput
    style = {{ minHeight: 100 }}
  />
  ...
</ScrollView>
```