# How to handle TextInput in scrollView nested in View react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a code like this:

```
<View>
  <View></View>
  <ScrollView>
    <View>
      <TextInput/>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
  <View></View>
</View>
```

How can I handle it to response correctly to keyboard?
Both android and ios???
i have 2 permenant views top and bottom of the screen, this views pushed up on keyboard show

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43854912/react-native-keyboardavoidingview-covers-last-text-input/48860983#48860983

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide keyboard in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685421/hide-keyboard-in-react-native)

Comment: i have done it before but textinput goes under keboard

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really unclear, but what I think you need is [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview).

It's a built-in React Native component that resizes based on the keyboard height.

Comment: my problem is the inside keyboard covers inner scrollview's content

Comment: Well since KeyboardAvoidingView resizes when the keyboard is open, all of its elements will come a bit higher (obviously), so your input shouldn't be covered.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the keyboard is not overlapping any important bits of your layout such as your text Input wrap your whole screen in KeyboardAvoidingView

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview

Answer (score -1):

Solved!!
I solved it by handling the display of elements (views) on keyboard show and hide by keyboard in react native docs